# How Do I Programmatically Force Custom Permalinks with My Theme?

Tags: theme-development, permalinks, htaccess

I'm making a custom theme. It's a highly specialized theme to make WordPress into like an application rather than a CMS system or blog. For instance, a Dental Office Scheduling System (with CMS and widget capabilities), as an example.

Because my theme needs pretty URLs to work properly, something I really need is for the .htaccess file to be that default that gets created only when someone sets Permalinks to Custom (and then types in something like %postname%). How do I trigger that in WordPress, programmatically, so that it creates this? I mean, I could probably overwrite the file myself during theme activation, but the better thing would be to use the WordPress API for it.

Comment: "my theme needs pretty URLs to work properly" why?

Comment: @ChristopherDavis because it's an app theme, not a regular theme. I have an MVC framework loaded inside a theme folder that operates heavily on rewrites.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To fully enable permalinks, you also need to ensure that .htaccess is also created. To do that, you need to set an option and flush the rules with a Boolean.

```
global $wp_rewrite; 

//Write the rule
$wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure('/%postname%/'); 

//Set the option
update_option( "rewrite_rules", FALSE ); 

//Flush the rules and tell it to write htaccess
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules( true );
```

If you use this in a plugin, it needs to be in the `init` hook, ***not*** the `load` hook. If it's in the `load` hook, it will throw an error saying `$wp_rewrite` is null.

**Important:** You should also have a conditional so this is only set once. (You can create an option and check if it's set, if not then you run this permalink code and set that option)

I also typically check if it's the admin side and only run it if it is.

Comment: You should not flush rewrites on `init`, never. It is expensive and slows your page load times dramatically. Rewrite rules are saved in the db, so flushing rewrites on `init` means that there will be a lot of db calls to resave rewrite rules on **every pageload**

Comment: @PieterGoosen Read the rest of my answer. What I do is I check if it's been set and only set it once (so when I first install the plugin) and it never runs again. I also check if it's `is_admin()` but that's not necessary if it's only run once.

Comment: Add that info in your answer. That is important info that your answer need to make it more acceptable ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen done.  (Although I already had it in my answer except for the "is_admin()" piece)

Answer (score 6):

```
function change_permalinks() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure('/%postname%/');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'change_permalinks');
```

You may not need the action hook if you're sticking this in your theme activation function code.

I also found that this only slightly worked. You still have to click the Permalinks settings page for that .htaccess file to be created. So, what to do? Well, I found I could use an IFRAME that loads that page automatically for me from my theme's options panel, and then it would create that .htaccess file for me.

```
<iframe style="position:absolute;top:-5000px" src="<?= site_url() ?>/wp-admin/options-permalink.php"></iframe>
```

Comment: Calling flush_rules on the init action is a bad, bad idea. It might be acceptable in an activation or installation function call, but not on init.

Comment: I know this is old, but you *can* get it to rewrite the ".htaccess" file by changing your flush rules to this: `update_option( "rewrite_rules", FALSE ); $wp_rewrite->flush_rules( true );` This will write the ".htaccess" file.

Comment: @DonRhummy please post it as an answer and I'll mark it as the new answer.

Comment: @Volomike i added the answer

Answer (score 2):

This is how I use this, to only occur when my theme is activated, and only if there is no pre-existing setting saved (to not break something done before my theme is used).

```
/*
 * Set permlinks on theme activate
 */
    function set_custom_permalinks() {
        $current_setting = get_option('permalink_structure');

        // Abort if already saved to something else
        if($current_setting) {
            return
        }

        // Save permalinks to a custom setting, force create of rules file
        global $wp_rewrite;
        update_option("rewrite_rules", FALSE);
        $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure('/news/%postname%/');
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);
    }
    add_action('after_switch_theme', 'set_custom_permalinks');
```

The advantage of this is that it will only run once when the theme is activated, not every time WordPress is loaded by a visit to the site.