# Making permalinks to /%postname%/ by default in installation

Tags: permalinks

I am making a custom wordpress distribution I will use for my own sites including my language and a child theme. But, I want the permalinks to be /%postname%/ by default so that I don't need to change this in the setting after installation.

How can I do this?

Comment: See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37010/1014). It provides exactly what you need.

Comment: Where do I edit/add that code? Which file?

Comment: This would reside in your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: "*Where do I edit/add that code? Which file?*" - If you're making a custom WordPress distribution, you really should already know how to answer this question. That said, I would recommend putting it in a Plugin that you bundle with your custom distribution.

Comment: also make sure you don't run that code each run since running `flush_rules();` is a very big on resources and with that function hooked on init meaning it will run on every page load

Answer (score 1):

i wrote an article recently about how to customize your install (including setting permalinks) with install.php

http://www.kathyisawesome.com/421/customizing-wordpress-install/

Comment: I got an error trying to access your site.

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /421/customizing-wordpress-install/ on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: you too? weird, b/c i have heard that from someone else, but i (and others) can see it just fine.  cloudflare must have something against scandinavians.